# How do I debug what's wrong when the Endpoints framework stops generating the WEB-INF/*.api-file?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Given a Google Cloud Endpoints project in Eclipse with the servlet-class annotated with `@Api(name="helloworld")`, the Endpoints framework generates a file named `war/WEB-INF/helloworld-v1.api` when the project compiles successfully. Sometimes this file is *not* generated even if there are no compilation errors though - only what I will call "GAE Endpoints code convention errors".

**Example - working:**

```
public class TestEntity {
    public String Text;
    public TestEntity(String text){
        Text = text;
    }
}

@ApiMethod
public TestEntity getTestEntity(){
    return new TestEntity("Hello world"); 
}
```

**Example - NOT working:**

```
// The TestEntity-class is unchanged
@ApiMethod
public TestEntity getTestEntity(String input){
    return new TestEntity("Hello world"); 
}
```

The problem with the latter example is that I take a String parameter as input without annotating it with `@Named`. I know that in this example, but there might be other cases where this is not so obvious.

Is there anywhere where I can read some sort of error log on why the .api file is not generated?

Although I am a fan of code by convention, it really takes the programming efficiency a step back if I cannot get feedback on what I do wrong. Eclipse provides compiler error feedback. The Google Cloud Endpoints Framework should provide Code-By-Convention-Rule-Breaking feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't currently good logging or error messaging when code generation fails, though it's one of the (if not most) requested features. In the interim, here's a list of the common failure cases:

1. **The return type is invalid.** Return types must be objects conforming to JavaBean conventions, and types like `Object`, `String`, and `Integer` are not allowed.
2. **One or more argument types are invalid.** Methods may accept at most one object in the `POST` body, and this object should also conform to JavaBean conventions. Methods may accept zero or more arguments via the query string (using the `@Named` annotation) and these must be scalar types (e.g. `String`, `Integer`).
3. **An API, method, or parameter has an invalid name.** APIs, methods, and parameters should be named to match the following regular expression: `[a-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*`. Convention also suggests using `lowerCamelCase` for naming (though `alllowercase` is allowed).

Comment: To add another tip to Dan's answer, I have found that the discovery file can get cached by my browser during development. The symptom is that everything on the server looks OK, no errors, but the API explorer doesn't display my APIs. By opening Chrome Devtools (which I have configured to not use cache), the API Explorer works.